# Kotlin app can't find file even though it exists

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a Kotlin app where I need to access the Cookies file located at /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies. However, when I try to access the file, I get a "file not found" error, even though the file definitely exists at that location.

I've double-checked the file path and made sure there are no typos (I can see the file with adb shell and Amaze File Manager), and I've also checked that the app has permission to access the file (app has root permissions).

First I was trying to open and read the file directly and I got the error:

```
04-20 13:42:52.590 25419 25419 E AndroidRuntime: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies' with flags 0x1: Directory /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default doesn't exist
```

I though maybe Chrome was running so I couldn't open the file directly so I tried copying it to a temp folder and reading that:

```
var proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su --preserve-environment -c cp "+tempCookiesDatabaseFile.absolutePath+" "+CHROME_COOKIES_DATABASE_FILE.absolutePath)
var exitVal = proc.waitFor()
if (exitVal != 0) {
    val errorStream: InputStream = proc.getErrorStream()
    val stderrReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(errorStream))
    for (line in stderrReader.lines()) {
        Log.e("CookieSwapper", line)
    }
}
```

But that still fails:

`04-20 14:52:22.565 31774 31774 E CookieSwapper: cp: bad '/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies': No such file or directory`

Is there anything else I can try to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you check what are the permissions on the "/Default" directory, as opposed to the file ?

Comment: drwx------ 38 u0_a191 u0_a191 4.0K 2023-04-20 17:19 Default @Greycon

Comment: -rw-------   1 u0_a191 u0_a191 1.1M 2023-04-20 17:16 Cookies